# When you know what week it is, how to find out the start date of the week

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

Through the 'date-fns' module, I am receiving numbers of how many weeks the date is this year.

```
const current = '2022-03-10'
const weekNumber = getWeek(current, 1) // 11
```

On the contrary, if you only know the numbers, you want to know how to do the first date of the week number.

The way I want to know.

```
const weekNumber = 11;
const weekOfstartDate = anyFunc(weekNumber) // '2022-03-07'
```

Do you know the answer to this solution?

Comment: That's simply not possible. Week `1` can correspond to `2022-01-04` or `2022-01-05` or even `1994-01-04`, and you have no way to tell which it is, the information is lost.

Comment: @Kaiido Is it possible if we limit it to 2022 years only?

Comment: No, you can't tell apart the 7 days that compose the given week.

Comment: What's your start of the week? Is it sunday or monday?

Comment: @Kaiido - If the starting point came from `date-fns`'s [`getWeek`](options.weekStartsOn), you can determine that *"...the first date of the week number..."* for 2022 is the day defined by `options.weekStartsOn`.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB - `date-fns` has an option for that (which is used by `getWeek`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah you think that's what they want? I was under the impression they wanted to retrieve any day in that week but you're probably right. They would also need the value of `firstWeekContainsDate` though, since the 1st of January 2022 was actually on week 51 of the year 2021.

Comment: (Oops, meant to post the URL, not the option name twice. :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the I token:

```
var dateFns = require("date-fns");
console.log(dateFns.parse('10','I', new Date()));
```

At [npm.runkit.com](https://npm.runkit.com/date-fns) that returns a date for Mon 7 Mar 2022. It seems date-fns assumes the year of the current week. I have no idea how to specify the year, attempting:

```
console.log(dateFns.parse('2022-10','YYYY-II', new Date(),{
  useAdditionalWeekYearTokens: true
}));
```

Throws a range error: The format string mustn't contain `YYYY` and `II` at the same time. Similarly for "2022W10" and tokens "YYYY'W'II", it says Y and I tokens can't be in the same format string.

A function to do the same thing is:

```js
// Returns the first day (Monday) of the specified week
// Year defaults to the current local calendar year
function getISOWeek(w, y = new Date().getFullYear()) {
  let d = new Date(y, 0, 4);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay() || 7) + 1 + 7*(w - 1));
  return d;
}

// Mon Mar 14 2022
console.log(getISOWeek(11).toString());
// Mon Jan 02 2023
console.log(getISOWeek(1,2023).toString());
// Mon Dec 28 2026
console.log(getISOWeek(53,2026).toString());
```

A robust function should validate the input such that the week number is 1 to 53 and that 53 is only permitted for years that have 53 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a solution only using date-fns functions. This is how i combined it:

```
const result = setWeek(nextMonday(new Date(year, 0, 4)), week, {
    weekStartsOn: 1,
    firstWeekContainsDate: 4,
  });
```